# Error while setuping CodeSniffer in PhpStorm with remote interpreter

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I have setup remote interpreter with php7.2. Now I want to setup remote CodeSniffer. I have setup it remotely with pear. However now I PhpStorm does not allow me to select remote interpreter. It shows the following:

> CodeSniffer is saved in IDE settings, but selected interpreter is defined in Project settings. Please, select another interpreter or change visibility for this one.

I wonder how I can change visibility for CodeSniffer. Is it possible to use remote remote CodeSniffer at all?

Comment: As I understand IDE wants Remote Interpreter to be marked as "Visible only for this project" in order to be able to use it for CodeSniffer. Have you tried that?

Comment: @LazyOne I had it. Just tried to disable and it works. Strange. As I understand codesniffer settings can be saved only in IDE and are project agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Code Sniffer settings and bound remote interpreter settings should be stored on the same level of settings (project or application) in order to keep PhpStorm settings in consistent state.

Unfortunately, till PhpStorm 182.2371 there was a limitation which doesn't allow to store PHP Code Sniffer/Mess Detector settings on project level (please see details in corresponding issue [WI-19525](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19525)), so there was no way to bind PHP Code Sniffer/Mess Detector to interpreter defined on project level settings and this error message appeared.

Please update your PhpStorm version, it should work fine starting from PhpStorm 182.2371